# MySQL Cluster setup, receiving error "Specify node id"

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, mysql-cluster

I am attempting to set up a MySQL Cluster.

I have the following setup:

- One management node
- Two data nodes
- One SQL node

Below is the `config.ini` file:

```
[ndbd default]
# Options affecting ndbd processes on all data nodes:
NoOfReplicas=1     # Number of replicas

DataMemory=256M    # How much memory to allocate for data storage

IndexMemory=128M   # How much memory to allocate for index storage


#Directory for Data Node
DataDir=/var/lib/mysql-cluster

[ndb_mgmd]

# Management process options:
HostName=x.x.x.21

datadir=/var/lib/mysql-cluster

# Storage Nodes
[NDBD]

HostName=x.x.x.188
DataDir= /var/lib/mysql-cluster

[NDBD]

HostName=x.x.x.189
DataDir= /var/lib/mysql-cluster

# Setup node IDs for MySQL API-servers (clients of the cluster)
[mysqld]
# SQL node options:
hostname=x.x.x.22
```

Below is `my.cnf` file

```
[mysqld]

ndbcluster # run NDB storage engine

ndb-connectstring=X.X.X.21 # location of management server

[mysql_cluster]

ndb-connectstring=X.X.X.21 # location of management server
```

But when I start command `ndb_mgmd -f /etc/config.ini --initial`
I am getting the following error:

> MySQL Cluster Management Server mysql-5.6.28 ndb-7.4.10
>
> 2018-05-09 14:29:08 [MgmtSrvr] ERROR    -- Could not determine which nodeid to use for this node. Specify it with --ndb-nodeid= on command line

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer: I'm no expert on NDB Cluster)

A few options to try:

Have you tried `ndb_mgmd` with the `--no-nodeid-checks` option?

[Description on the ndb_mgmd documentation page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-cluster-programs-ndb-mgmd.html#option_ndb_mgmd_no-nodeid-checks)

As the error message suggests, maybe try `ndb_mgmd` with the `--ndb-nodeid=` option? I'm guessing any small number might be valid. (Note: guessing!)

[Description on the Common NDB Options documentation page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-cluster-program-options-common.html#option_ndb_common_ndb-nodeid)

Answer (score 0):

To keep things simple I am always specifying node ids in config.ini:

```
[NDB_MGMD]
NodeId=1
hostname=10.xxx.xxx.xxx

[NDBD]
NodeId=10
hostname=10.xxx.xxx.xxx
datadir=/mysql/cluster

[NDBD]
NodeId=11
hostname=10.xxx.xxx.xxx
datadir=/mysql/cluster

[MYSQLD]
NodeId=20
[MYSQLD]
NodeId=21
[MYSQLD]
NodeId=22
...
```